# Instalação do Android studio no Ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu

É a primeira vez que instalo o android-studio, instalei com os comandos:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

À primeira vista correu tudo bem, o problema é que não o consigo encontrar da maneira 'user-friendly', adiciona-lo à 'launch bar'

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

consigo abrir só o *Android SDK Manager* a partir do terminal com o comando `android` já com o comando `android studio` aparecem as opções mas se tentar algumas delas, estas não são reconhecidas/executadas voltando a aperecer a lista de opções.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A solução até deve/pode ser básica mas nunca mexi no *Android Studio*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baixe o arquivo .DEB neste site:

https://paolorotolo.github.io/android-studio/

Entre no diretório pelo Terminal e execute o(s) seguinte(s) comando(s), informando logo em seguida a senha para executar como administrador:

```
sudo apt-get remove android-studio 
sudo dpkg -i nome_do_arquivo.deb
```

Você pode também fazer desta maneira, baixando o arquivo com extensão .tgz, extrair em um diretório do Linux e apontar o caminho para o arquivo (segundo site):

http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2013/10/23/how-to-install-android-studio-in-ubuntu-linux-13-10/

https://askubuntu.com/questions/67925/how-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut-in-unity

Comment: Mas isso como o site indica é o equivalente aos comandos que eu usei para instalar, certo?

Comment: Certo, mas experimente desta maneira e verifique se o ícone aparece. Instalo desta maneira utilizando o Debian com interface gráfico Gnome se não me engano, tem outra maneira também, assim que tiver tempo edito minha resposta e informo ela para você.

Comment: Então agora desinstalo, certo? `sudo apt-get --purge remove android-studio`? e depois instalo dessa maneira não é?

Comment: Isso mesmo, coloquei rapidamente outra forma de instalar o Android Studio, com a extração de um arquivo .tgz para um diretório do Ubuntu e criando um atalho na Unity. Faço desta maneira com o Debian e interface gráfica Gnome.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui da seguinte maneira: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_1767143059&feature=iv&src_vid=qfinKxwYYZs&v=Yz2l-4GDpZE
 e 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfinKxwYYZs, mas Obgado pelas sugestões

Comment: De nada, precisando só chamar.

Answer (score 0):

remove o android-studio ---> sudo apt autoremove android-studio
 e depois instala manualmente atravez da loja do Ubuntu e faça as configuraçoes necessarias